# Pwa / Web app "restarts" after Google login

Tags: google-chrome, reactjs, web-applications, authentication, progressive-web-apps

We have a project built in react thats using service worker and manifest for Pwa functions. We use google and facebook to login to the app. 
Problem: When running it in Chrome browser (not fullframe) and login to the with eg. google its no problem. When i save it to homescreen and use it in standalone mode (pwa) and hit the our login btn ,google login window opens and i pic an account to login whith. After that the pwa restarts with the splashscreen and im back to where im started Not logged in. Please help

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/#add_a_splash_screen),

> When you launch your web app from the home screen a number of things happen behind the scenes:
>
> 1. Chrome launches.
> 2. The renderer that displays the page starts up.
> 3. Your site loads from the network (or from cache if it has a service
>    worker).

If you haven't done so, you may want to check [Introduction to Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker) for more information.

With this, you may want to try [let the user automatically sign back in](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/credential-management-api#let_the_user_automatically_sign_back_in) to avoid this logging redirect problem.

Additional code reference, see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985784/redirection-in-progressive-web-app).